# NO_PUBKEY after sudo apt update

Tags: debian, raspbian, openmediavault, apt-key, jellyfin

I wanted to update my repos on Raspbian server on which I have installed OMV and Jellyfin but I still get this error:

```
Err:6 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131
Err:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 112695A0E562B32A NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853
Hit:11 https://repo.jellyfin.org/raspbian bullseye InRelease
```

I tried to update my keys using

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys [KEY]
```

but it always wrote back

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.XeqKS2rgOx/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys [KEY]
gpg: key [KEY]: "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (12/bookworm) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

Anyone knows what could be wrong?
Thanks